# Location of google calendar in company domain

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

where is location of google calendar, we have google paid account but I could not found company calendar, where I need to add my service account to fetch event. I could not found it using admin account.

My Problem is I want to add service account email into share setting

Comment: From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth#perform-google-apps-domain-wide-delegation-of-authority), In enterprise applications you can access the users data without any manual authorization on their part. In Google Apps domains, the domain administrator can grant to third party applications domain-wide access to its users' data. To delegate authority this way, domain administrators can use [service accounts with OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount).

Comment: thankyou @KENdi I setup application as per document, could you please tell me in which calendar I need to add  my service account for shearing. or it's not require in  'domain-wide access'.